# xmrpool.net Correct Address?

Tags: mining-pools

I got everything set up and working on xmrpool.net and am working towards my first payment. I just want the payment to go to my wallet. In my config file I have my address as an integrated address. Is that ok and will I get paid? Or should I have just used my wallet address (with no payment id). I'm fairly new to this so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you have more than 0.3 XMR because it is the minimum payout value.

[Pool Config](https://xmrpool.net/#/home):

```
PPLNS Fee                   0.6%
Solo Fee                    0.4%
BTC Fee                     1.5%
Minimum payout (Wallet)     0.3 XMR
Minimum payout (BTC)        4 XMR
Minimum payout (Exchange)   4 XMR
```